# Rails4: Link to A Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have a User's Show Page where

1.) Routes

```
get 'users/:id' => 'user#show', as: :user
```

2.) user_controller.rb

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: :show

def show
    @user = User.find_by_name(params[:id]) # for name instead of id
@listings = @user.listings
end
end
```

and i can link to it via "**current_user**".

**I wanted to create a Shop Controller**, so i followed the same steps. I Generated a Shops Controller and modified the routes and controller as follow:

1.) Routes

```
get 'users/:id' => 'user#show', as: :user
get 'shop/:id' => 'shop#show', as: :shop
```

2.) shop_controller.rb

```
class ShopController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: :show

def show
    @user = User.find_by_name(params[:id]) # for name instead of id
    @listings = @user.listings
end

end
```

This Works only if im at the User's Page (localhost:3000/users/test) and then click the link to the controller. then it switches to (localhost:3000/shop/test).

If i try to click the link anywhere else im getting

[image]

The link is ->

```
<li><%= link_to "My Shop", :controller => "shop", :action => "show" %></li>
```

I'm fairly new to Rails, if someone could enlighten me it would be very nice :)

Comment: Hi. Do you really want to find users by name? I think using id is a better way.

Comment: It's strictly visual and functional. But i don't think that's the problem :(

Comment: I think i'm my linking is wrong. But i'm still in the dark.

Comment: Can you put your Shop and Listing classes here. It's very small issue I am writing the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by classes ? :/ I'm new to Rails and still learning :) Sry

Comment: Following files
app/models/user.rb ,
app/models/shop.rb and
app/models/listing.rb

Comment: Guess this will help you more, My repo -> https://github.com/Theminijohn/flatx

Comment: Shop model hasn't been checked in, I think?

Comment: Just Merged it in, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First start with correcting names of your controllers as per rails conventions. Names  should be as follows.

controllers/**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: :show

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id]) # Because Id can't be same for two users but name can be.
        @listings = @user.listings
    end
end
```

And in case of shop_controller it is fine beacuse shop is not a model.

controllers/**shop_controller.rb**

```
class ShopController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: :show

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) # Id can't be same for two users but name can be.
    @listings = @user.listings
end

end
```

And give link like this.

```
<%= link_to "My Wonderful Shop", {:controller => "shop", :action => "show", :id => @user.id} %>
```

In your routes file

```
get 'shop/:id' => 'shop#show'
```

Comment: Still getting that error. I think it has something to do with how rails gets the shop :id or know where to link to.

Comment: Since you used `as: :shop`, you should be able to create the link with `<%= link_to 'My Shop', shop_path(@user) %>`.